# Esp8266 automatically creates a wifi without even calling WiFi.softAP()

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

begin(Ssid, Password) function to connect to a network. But a weird thing is happening. Even tough my module connects successfully to the wifi it starts broadcasting a wifi named ESP_D3F2A. I have never initialized it to AP mode. I want to get rid of this wifiAp, any solutions?

I am using arduino IDE to program esp8266.

Code Snippets :

```
bool connectWifi(){

   WiFi.begin(Ssid, Password); //SSID and PASS of wifi i want esp to connect to.
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
     delay(1000);
     if (wifiTimeout > WIFI_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT){
      #ifdef DEBUG
   Serial.println("Timeout");
   #endif
        return false;
     }
   wifiTimeout++;
   }
...
```

if this is successful I am just doing an infinite wait.

Answer (score 1):

Calling WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
just before WiFi.begin(Ssid, Password);
solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mine all do that too, I have three.  I shut them off.

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
```